# JQuery How To Flip A "Card" in 3D Space Like YP.com

Tags: jquery, css

If you go to [YP.com](http://yp.com) or Yellowpages, you'll see that they apply a 3D flip to the boxes towards the bottom when you mouse-over in a newer browser.

How is this accomplished in JQuery (by animating CSS3 props?)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is actually a lot closer to what he was looking for.. Just for the record..

:)

[Sponsor Flip Wall With jQuery & CSS](http://tutorialzine.com/2010/03/sponsor-wall-flip-jquery-css/)

It uses [Flip!](http://lab.smashup.it/flip/) as the foundation..

Answer (score 1):

It works on webkit browsers, so it isn't probably done by jQuery but by webkit css transforms (I did not analyze the code thoroughly so this is just an assumption but I think it's a right one).

You can get this effect in css by using:

```
-webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
```

You can find more information on webkit 3d transforms here:

[Surfin' Safari](http://www.webkit.org/blog/386/3d-transforms/)

Sadly, it won't work on non-webkit browsers.